# Finding the feature map that approximates the first three terms of Maclaurin series

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, machine-learning

Consider the Maclaurin series expansion
for the exponential function,

\begin{equation}
    e^t = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n!} = 1 + t + \frac{t^2}{2!} + \frac{t^3}{3!} + \ldots
\end{equation}

Using only the first three terms in this series, we obtain $\exp(t) \approx 1 + t + \frac{t^2}{2}$. Use this approximation to obtain a feature map $\phi: \mathbb{R}^D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^M$ such that, for arbitrary $q \in \mathbb{R}^D$ and $k \in \mathbb{R}^D$, we have $\exp(q^\top k) \approx \phi(q)^\top \phi(k)$. Express the dimensionality of the feature space $M$ as a function of $D$. What would be the dimensionality if you used $K \geq 3$ terms in the Maclaurin series expansion (as a function of $D$ and $K$)?

After putting some thought in this problem, I got the following feature map:

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\phi}(q) = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
      1 \\
      q \\
      \frac{q^2}{\sqrt{2}} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Is this solution correct? If yes, what is the dimensionality of the feature space?

Comment: Those who voted to close the question should explain what further context they feel is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is not correct. In order to build the correct feature map, it helps to consider a particular low-dimensional example in detail.

Take $D = 2$. Our approximation for $\exp(q^Tk)$ can be written as follows.
\begin{align}
1 + (q^Tk) + \frac{(q^Tk)^2}{2!} &= 
1+(q_1k_1 + q_2k_2) + \frac{(q_1k_1 + q_2k_2)^2}{2!}
\\ & = 1 + q_1k_1 + q_2k_2 + \frac 12 q_1^2k_1^2 + \frac 12 q_2^2 k_2^2 + q_1q_2 k_1k_2 
\end{align}
With each of the terms written out like this, it is easy to see that the following feature map will work:
$$
\phi(x) = (1,x_1,x_2,\frac 1{\sqrt{2}} x_1^2, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x_2^2, x_1x_2).
$$
I recommend that you verify with a detailed calculation that $\phi(q)^T\phi(k) = \exp(q^Tk)$.

To generalize this, we can take $\phi:\Bbb R^D \to \Bbb R^M$ to be something like
$$
\phi(x) = (1,x_1,\dots,x_D, x_1^2/\sqrt{2},\dots,x_D^2/\sqrt{2},x_1x_2, x_1x_3,\dots,x_2x_3,x_2x_4,\dots,x_{D-1}x_D).
$$
In this case, we have
$$
M = 1 + D + D + \frac{D(D-1)}{2} = \frac{D^2 + 3D + 2}{2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! In the meantime I reached the exact same solution. If we use K ≥ 3 terms in the MacLaurin series expansion, the dimensionality (as a function
of D and K) would be: \begin{equation}
    M = 1+D+\binom{2+D-1}{D-1}+...+\binom{K+D-1}{D-1} 
\end{equation}
Can you confirm this?

Comment: @PTSONIC Yes, your formula looks correct. By the way, the terms added are the [multiset coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets) $\left(\! \binom{D}{k}\! \right)$ for $k = 0,1,\dots,K$.